# Black screen when when starting android emulator in Genymotion

Tags: android, genymotion

When I start the virtual android device in Genymotion , the device has black screen and this is the message it shows in Virtual Box

[image]

Is there any easy way to fix that because I am very new in the Android Developement?

Comment: I think its emulator issue.

Uninstall your app and reinstall it.

Comment: Which app do you mean?

Comment: your app only..

Comment: I think the problem is not in the app but in Genymotion . When I try to start some virtual device I get this message from above.

Comment: That is what I am saying. Problem is not with app its bcz of some memory issue in emulator.

Comment: your operating system? your graphic card? genymotion usually have problem with outdated graphic drivers. do you happen to have nvidia graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for me it was due to virtualbox not creating the route needed for genymotion to connect to. Please check my answer at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503066/genymotion-black-screen-failed-to-connect-to-vm-tcpstream-for-main-host-conne/45656856#45656856), it might work for you.