# genymotion black screen: Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

Running genymotion w/virtualbox on ubuntu 17.04

Tried both the "Custom Tablet 7.1.0" and "Custom Phone 7.1.0" and neither one seems to boot: I just see a black screen perpetually.

I get this error in terminal:

```
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
```

I was able to get an android 7 machine working in virtualbox (although with lots of ergonomics issues), so I'm guessing it's not a hardware issue.

No idea how to debug this; haven't been able to find anything by googling.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this Answer here, as I just lost a day and a half of my life to this, which I will never get back! Just to confirm, there are a lot of posts around, with various fixes, none of which worked for me.

I had the same issue as above, genymotion launching as a black screen, launching from Terminal shows error

```
Failed to connect to VM (TcpStream) for main host connection, 
   IP:Port=192.168.56.101:25000!!!
```

For me, the issue was that virtualbox had not created the route for vboxnet0.

To confirm, Install net-tools, and check your routes

```
$ sudo apt install net-tools
$ route -n
```

Your looking for an ip in the same range as your error, in this case: 192.168.56.0. If it's not there you'll need to add it.

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.56.0/24 dev vboxnet0
```

Go back to genymotion, clear your cache -> settings -> misc -> clear cache, and then reload your device.

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be the IP configuration of Virtual Box. Check to make sure the IP listed in Host-only Network inside Preferences is the same as your local IP.